# Slightly Chunky Cantor Sets

Tags: lebesgue-measure, fractals

I'm familiar with the construction of so-called "fat" Cantor sets (e.g. the Volterra construction), where a Cantor-type construction is used to construct a nowhere-dense set of positive Lebesgue measure, and thus has full Hausdorf dimension. Is there a similar construction for such a set with full Hausdorf dimension, but with null Lebesgue measure? Alternatively, can it be shown that such a Cantor construction cannot be done?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to construct a set Lebesgue measure zero set with Hausdorff dimension 1 is to first construct a set $C_n$ with Hausdorff dimension $1-1/n$.  It sounds like you already know that this can be done via a Cantor like construction where each interval is decomposed into two sub-intervals whose length is $2^{-n/(n-1)}$ times the length of it's parent.  Then, these are all null sets, so the set
$$\bigcup_{n=2}^{\infty}C_n$$
satisfies your needs.

If, on the other hand, you want to mimic Cantor's construction more directly (to obtain, for example, a perfect set), then you might try to construct approximations $C_n$, where each $C_n$ consists of $2^n$ disjoint intervals of Length 
$$\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}+2}\right)^n.$$

Note that
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} 2^n\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}+2}\right)^n = 0,$$
so that the intersection of all the $C_n$s is Lebesgue null.  On the other hand,
$$\lim_{n\to \infty } \,
   \frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt
   {n+1}+2}\right)^{n+1}}{\left(\frac{1}{
   2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}+2}\right)^n} = \frac{1}{2},$$
so we might expect get Hausdorff dimension 1.  Proving that might be hard, assuming it's right. You might look at [the mass distribution principle](https://www.google.com/search?q=falconer+mass+distribution+principle).